# PHP get the number between mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

Example we have a database with 3000+ members, we want to create a unique `nid` which can be use to sort the members by their name.

Example of my database:

```
name   | nid
----------------------
Alex   | A0091384712
CK     | C0312897412
Joan   | J01234567890
Joey   | J8401928374
Kelvin | K7512835830
```

how can i generate new `nid` for new object name `Joe` that sort(order by `name`) between `Joan` & `Joey` , the result(`nid`) i want to get is J3583680242 (which is (8401928374-01234567890)/2)

Comment: What happens when you insert a user between 100 and 101?

Comment: There is no way you should be doing this!  You need to change how you are solving your problem.

Comment: @Incognito the new user will become 101 and 101 will become 102

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should clarify the question:
Why do you need to insert with an id between two previous users?

But I agree with Toby Allen, you probably should rethink the problem, because that is not common at all.
Try autogenerating unique IDs with `uniqid()` ([PHP's uniqid function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)) and with that you might not have this problem.